# Squid proxy too slow when ipfilter is active on FreeBSD

Tags: performance, freebsd, squid

Squid 2.7 - FreeBSD 8.2

The internet experience with squid is too slow when ipfilter is enabled. This is my current configuration:

rl0 = internal LAN
bge0 = internet WAN

ipf.rules:

```
pass out quick on rl0 all
pass in quick on rl0 all 

# out to internet 
pass out quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to any port = 8080 flags S keep state
pass out quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to any port = 80 flags S keep state 
pass out quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to any port = 443 flags S keep state

# Query to internet provider DNS
pass out quick on bge0 proto tcp from any to x.x.x.x port = 53 flags S keep state
pass out quick on bge0 proto udp from any to x.x.x.x port = 53 keep state 

# protect my network
block out log first quick on bge0 all
block in log first quick on bge0 all

# others
pass in quick on lo0 all
pass out quick on lo0 all
```

Internet connection works fine when i open all traffic:

```
pass in quick on bge0 all
pass out quick on bge0 all
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

IPfilter in FreeBSD is a bit unmaintained. Have you tried to use PF instead?